# Overwriting eventViewer in "eventViewer = null" leaks the resource that "eventViewer refers to in C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, coverity, resource-leak

```
 for (int i = 0; i < auditList.Count; i++)
            {
                audit = (XEAudit)auditList[i];
                XEEventViewer eventViewer = audit.GetEventViewer();
                if (eventViewer != null)
                {
                    while (eventViewer.NextEvent())
                    {
                        if ((eventViewer.GetSeverity() == "Normal") || (eventViewer.GetSeverity() == "Critical"))
                            validationFailed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                    //);

                    //We assume that there is only one request per call so we will return the 
                    // first data content
                    if (validationFailed == true)
                    {
                        StandardException innerException = traverseDN(OutermostException); ;
                        OutermostException = innerException;
                    }
                }
                //To avoid Resource leak
                eventViewer = null;

            }
```

Above is the line of code where in I am trying to resolve the error :

Overwriting eventViewer in "eventViewer = null" leaks the resource that "eventViewer refers to.

I have tried to use eventViewer.Dispose() too after assigning it to null. But not sure why its not helping out.

Comment: What is `XEEventViewer`? If it is disposable, calling Dispose() is all you can do. `eventViewer = null` does nothing, you should also have a warning or a hint in the error list. How do you know that something leaks? Did you run the diagnostics tool?

Comment: Yes. I ran the Coverity tool.. and below is what I received :

Overwriting eventViewer in "eventViewer = null" leaks the resource that "eventViewer refers to.

Comment: Probably because XEEventViewer is disposable and you don't dispose it. You can safely remove `eventViewer = null`.

Comment: So removing the "eventViewer = null" and adding eventViewer.Dispose() ?

Comment: Even better, put eventViewer in a using block: `using(XEEventViewer eventViewer = audit.GetEventViewer()) { ... }`